# No se coloca el texto en el hintText de un dropdownbuttonformfield de la opcion seleccionada en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

cuando selecciona una opción de este dropdownbuttomformfield me aparece este texto de "Widget" en lugar del texto de la opción seleccionada, esto sucede cuando hago la selección desde la aplicación instalada con el APK, pero no sucede cuando la depuró, que puede ser lo que sucede?

lo armo de esa manera debido a que tengo tambien un input que me carga una imagen ya sea de una foto o adjuntandola, pero al momento de cargar la foto me lo reiniciaba el valor del dropdown. Cargando de esta forma el hintText del dropdown no se refresaca pero en la version del apk no aparece el texto de la opcion selecciona sino el texto de Widget.

este es codigo del build:

```
String textoProveedor = "";

  List<DropdownMenuItem> listaProveedores = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Map argumentos = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;  

    final _imageInfo =  Provider.of<ProviderVale>(context, listen: true);

    usuarioId = argumentos['usuarioId'];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(
          child: Text("Registro de Remito"),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            remitoInput(),
            fechaInput(),
            proveedorSelect(argumentos['valeID'], argumentos['unidad'], _imageInfo),
            combustibleSelect(),
            litrosInput(),
            montoInput(),
            imagenRemito(_imageInfo),
            botonRegistrarRemito(argumentos['valeID']),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

este es el codigo del dropdownbuttomformfield

```
proveedorSelect(int valeId, String unidad, proveedor){
   return FutureBuilder(
      future: proveedores.recuperarProveedores(valeId),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Aguarde un Instante, estamos recuperando los reclamos"),
                CircularProgressIndicator()
              ],
            )
          ); 
        } 

        List data = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);

        listaProveedores = data.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(item['Vac_proveedor_des']), value: item['Vac_proveedor_id'].toString())).toList();

        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
          child: listaProveedores == null ? Container():DropdownButtonFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: textoProveedor == "" ? "Seleccione Un Proveedor" : textoProveedor,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        const Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                ),
               proveedor.ProveedorTexto.toString(),
                onChanged: (value) async {
                  proveedorSeleccionado = int.parse(value);
                  proveedorController.text = proveedorSeleccionado.toString();
                  if(proveedorSeleccionado != 0)
                  {
                    final listaCombustibles = await combustible.recuperarCombustibles(proveedorSeleccionado, unidad);
                    List data = jsonDecode(listaCombustibles);
                    itemsCombustibles = data.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(item['Vac_combustible_des']), value: item['Vac_combustible_id'].toString())).toList();
                    //proveedor.Proveedor = proveedorSeleccionado.toString();
                    //proveedor.ProveedorTexto = listaProveedores.firstWhere((item) => item.value == value).child.toString().replaceAll('Text("', '').replaceAll('")', '');
                    counter.value += 1;
                  }
                },
                items: listaProveedores   
              ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

[image: Esta es la imagen de la captura del apk]

[image: Esta es la imagen de la captura del debug]

Answer (score 0):

veo que en tu código sólo estás consultado sobre este estado, en tu primer if...
if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
Sin embargo, el resto del código lo estas dejando fuera de una consulta de estado de tu snapshot...
Entonces prueba colocando un else al ConnectionState.waiting y mete todo el código dentro de un posible ConnectionState.done y debieras además tener uno con código para el estado ConnectionState.error